# one regular expression that can work for two different string url's

Tags: java, regex

```
public String getContextName() {
    String contextName = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                         .getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath();
    String uri = "localhost/gar/garmin-first/gar_home";
    Pattern pat=Pattern.compile("/(.*?)/(.*)/");
    Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(uri);
    matcher.find();
    System.out.println("matched"+matcher.group(1)+matcher.group(2));
    if (StringUtil.isNotEmpty(contextName) && 
        contextName.contains(matcher.group(1))) {

        return matcher.group(2);
    }
    return matcher.group(1);
}
```

The output in the console will be printed as `group(1) = gar`,and `group(2) = garmin-first`, but what I really need is one regular expression that can work for both the cases. The other case is:

```
String uri = "localhost/garmin-first/gar_home";
```

In this case I need the output as `group(1) = garmin-first` and `group(2)` should be left empty. Can you please help me out
with a regular expression that can work for both the cases please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package test;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] strings = new String[]
        { "localhost/gar/garmin-first/gar_home", "localhost/garmin-first/gar_home" };
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(?<=/)(.*?)(?=/)");
        for(String s : strings)
        {
            System.out.println("For: " + s);
            Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(s);
            while (matcher.find())
            {
                System.out.println(matcher.group());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've changed the regex subtly so that we are looking for words that are surrounded by "/".
Hopefully you can find a useful way to get the parts you need because I don't think .group(1) and .group(2) will work now that we are looking for multiple matches in the same string.

Comment: :firstly thanks for your answer,so will this work for any type of urls that can be derived like this String contextName = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() .getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath(); String uri = (((HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() .getExternalContext().getRequest()).getRequestURI());,as the main reason for using this is for performance tuning

Comment: It'll work for any combination of string, you'll just need to watch out on what is returned. a/b/c/d returns b & c, a/b/c/d/ will return b, c & d. If your paths get any deeper, it will return others as well. (a/b/c/d/e/f will get you b, c, d & e)

Comment: :Got one more requirement added over to our application,the regex which we provided should accept the upper case letter aswell.Unfortunately in our case its not accepting that one.Is there any way that modifications in our current regex can help us resolve that issue.Thanks